# How to make KDE Applications' Toolbars Dark in Ubuntu?

Tags: 13.10, themes, window, kde-apps

Is there a way to make KDE Applications, running in Ubuntu 13.10, have dark tool bars?  For example, see the Gedit toolbar in the image below. The toolbar is dark, with light icons and text, but the Kate toolbar is light grey.  (I do not want the rest of the window elements below the tool bar to be dark, as can be done by simply selecting a dark theme using the KDE System Settings dialog).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning on customizing the toolbar colors, you can always try to modify your theme.

In the terminal, you can run:

```
sudo nautilus
```

This will allow you to get root privileges for your file explorer.

In /usr/share/themes and /usr/share/icons there are themes and icons to give you an example of how to make your own.

I recommend copying these files and editing them to see their effects.

Don't forget to use the [Unity Tweak Tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-tweak-tool/) to try out the changes you've made.

If you don't like your changes, you can always revert back to the original with the tweak tool.

Good luck!

Comment: Ryan, thanks for this suggestion...  I was looking for the specific changes I could make to the theme files to achieve dark toolbars.  Also, I'm not sure if changing the gtk theme files (in /usr/share/themes/) would have an effect on the the KDE applications, or if we have to make changes to files in /usr/share/kde4/?